# How to post an ajax request while another is in process in jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a feature using **html, jquery, php, c++, mysql**.

I have posted an ajax call to c++(using protocols) via php to do an installation in a server machine, which will take some time to process it and send back the response.

In between I need to show the installation progress in UI by taking value from a table.

Where the table value will be updated in the backend(c++) during installation.

Now I'm trying to show the progress details from same mysql table using php in UI using another ajax call once the main ajax request has been called.

But I'm getting response for the second ajax call once the result obtained from the first ajax call.

Now how can I get the values in between?

```
RemoteInstallationProg();
var formPostData = "";
formPostData = "submitType=13";
formPostData = formPostData + "&";
formPostData = formPostData + "reqType=" + reqType;
formPostData = formPostData + "&";
formPostData = formPostData + "saveHost=" + document.getElementById('serhostName').value;
formPostData = formPostData + "&";
formPostData = formPostData + "saveUser=" + document.getElementById('serUserName').value;
var tarHttpdFile = doc.txtHttpdFile.value;
httpReq = GetXmlHttpRequestObject();
if(httpReq)
{
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = GetResultXML;
    httpReq.open("POST", tarHttpdFile, true);
    httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpReq.send(formPostData);
}

function RemoteInstallationProg(){
var tarHttpdFile = SG_ROOT_PATH+"data/check.sgp";
var remotePost = "";
remotePost = "remoteIns=1";
remotePost = remotePost + "&";
remotePost = remotePost + "hostname=" + $('#hostName').val();
$.ajax({
    url: tarHttpdFile,
    type: "POST",
    data: remotePost,
    success:function(result)
    {
        if((result != '') && (result != 2))
        {
            ShowUserAlert(lang_alert_ary['hyperv_stat_'+result],'info');
        }
        if((result != 10) && (result != 2))
        {
            RemoteInstallationProg();
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: it's simple you can you can use setTimeout function in Jquery

Comment: But i need to call continously to update the progress details.

Comment: if you use set time out function for 1 sec then when first function in progress then stop and  after 1 sec second function continue. first you use this then try

Comment: I have tried still no result.

Comment: oky i will give you result soon

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** PHP writes its session data to a file by default. When a request is made to a PHP script that starts the session (session_start()), this session file is locked. What this means is that if your web page makes numerous requests to PHP scripts, for instance, for loading content via Ajax, each request could be locking the session and preventing the other requests from completing. The other requests will hang on session_start() until the session file is unlocked. This is especially bad if one of your Ajax requests is relatively long-running.

**Solution:** The session file remains locked until the script completes or the session is manually closed. To prevent multiple PHP requests (that need $_SESSION data) from blocking, you can start the session and then close the session. This will unlock the session file and allow the remaining requests to continue running, even before the initial request has completed.
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session_write_close() function before second ajax request.

Please check this reference [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: I have tried this too but not working:( second requests are still pending until the first response arrives.